# How to add datepicker in custom report page in frontend?

Tags: magento-1.7

Is there any built in function to add datepicker in form fields. Please suggest. So far I have tried to put jquery plugin for datepicker. But I think that is not the right way.

project\report\application\views\result\index.php

to

Answer (score 0):

you can use like below

```
$dateFormatIso = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(
    Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT
);

$fieldset->addField('start_date', 'date', array(
    'name'      => 'start_date',
    'label'     => Mage::helper('your_namespace')->__('Start Date'),
    'image'     => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
    'format'    => $dateFormatIso,
    'disabled'  => $isElementDisabled,
    'class'     => 'validate-date validate-date-range date-range-custom_theme-from'
));
```

Comment: your_namespace  -- What to put?

Comment: I got fatal error - Fatal error: Call to a member function addField() on null

Comment: change $fieldset to your form field set

Comment: Can you please explain briefly. How to implement?

Comment: please add your code in question